# How can I clear label text after some amount of time from code behind in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am assigning some text to `Label` after `button` click as follows:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "Hello";
}
```

After some amount of time, say `30seconds`, I would like to clear the `Label` text. 
Can any one help me? 
I tried the following `script`, but it doesn't work for me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Label1').fadeOut(3000, function() {
        $(this).html(""); //reset the label after fadeout
    });
});
```

My design

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#<%= myLabel.ClientID %>').fadeOut(3000, function() {
                $(this).html(""); //reset the label after fadeout
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:Label id="myLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First include jQuery in your page. Than look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to run some code after specified time you need to wrap the code in ready handler in

```
setTimeout(code, timeInMsAfterWitchToRunCode)
```

call. What you are doing is fading out immediately over a 3 seconds time. 3000ms that you are passing is parameter to fadeOut function telling it how long fading out should take.

Here you have working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/VPrEZ/3/

Note that in case of ASP.NET app you should use:

```
$('#<%= Label1.ClientID %>')
```

to select label. That is because you don't know the id of the control until runtime when control has runat="server" attribute set.

Comment: Can i have the Jquery link for this

Comment: What do you mean jQuery link for this? Are you asking how to include jQuery in page? You can download it or use CDN servers. Here is info on that http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery

Comment: The script that i should include some thing like `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>`

Comment: You just entered it! Change src to where you take jquery from. Did you check my link in comment above.

Answer (score 2):

If this is Asp.Net WebApplication I think you should use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#<%= Label1.ClientID %>').fadeOut(3000, function() {
        $(this).html(""); //reset the label after fadeout
    });
});
```

Comment: EVen though it doesn't wrk for me

Comment: Can you post how you define your Label, I did a test it works fine.

Comment: perhaps not including jquery in the page?

Comment: ` <asp:Label id="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>` my lable declaration

Answer (score 0):

Be warned, that if you don't clear label's text on next postback you will got the same message again with each and every following postback. In my opinion it's better to show label text with client-side code rather to clear it. Or you may just clear label text each time in Page_Load.